# why do the alertdialog crashes my app everytime

Tags: android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

The problem is alertdialogue box not at all working and it crashes everytime

I checked each and every line with youtube,
but it cant be helped

here's the code:

````
public void showupdatedialogue(String id , String name){

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View dialog = inflater.inflate(R.layout.update,null);
        builder.setView(dialog);

        EditText naame = findViewById(R.id.name);
        EditText rollno = findViewById(R.id.roll);
        EditText cla = findViewById(R.id.clas);
        EditText date = findViewById(R.id.dob);
        EditText teacher = findViewById(R.id.teacher);
        Button up = findViewById(R.id.update);

        builder.setTitle("Updating" + " " + name + " " + "record");
        builder.show();

        up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String n = naame.getText().toString();
                String r = rollno.getText().toString();
                String c = cla.getText().toString();
                String d = date.getText().toString();
                String t = teacher.getText().toString();
                updatestudents(id,n,r,d,c,t);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"record updated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });


    }```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the findViewById() you should add dialog.findViewById()

```
public void showupdatedialogue(String id , String name){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View dialog = inflater.inflate(R.layout.update,null);
    builder.setView(dialog);

    EditText naame = dialog.findViewById(R.id.name);
    EditText rollno = dialog.findViewById(R.id.roll);
    EditText cla = dialog.findViewById(R.id.clas);
    EditText date = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dob);
    EditText teacher = dialog.findViewById(R.id.teacher);
    Button up = dialog.findViewById(R.id.update);

    builder.setTitle("Updating" + " " + name + " " + "record");
    builder.show();

    up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String n = naame.getText().toString();
            String r = rollno.getText().toString();
            String c = cla.getText().toString();
            String d = date.getText().toString();
            String t = teacher.getText().toString();
            updatestudents(id,n,r,d,c,t);

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"record updated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });


}
```